# How can I compare the message received after sending ajax request

Tags: ajax

I m sending ajax request using Firefox.
After completing the request I got a variable as response.

e.g I got message as "true" and I want to compare it with the string "true", as a rule of thumb the condition should be true.

But when I debug the source I saw some strange characters added to response as "\r\n\r\ntrue".
any solution.

Regards.

Comment: I think you are returning response from any file that has some space or characters .

Comment: They have been added by your code

Comment: It's added automatically by browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AJAX resonse you are receiving is adding those unwanted chars. Check your source.

Comment: Yes, Now I started to return the integer numbers.